# Entity Framework Core: saving uploaded file to joined table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a News table joined with a File table where I want to save images or pdfs associated with the News. Below is my model and the Create method where I am saving the posted file to the joined table.

However I get the following error. It doesn't make sense to me because NewsFiles shouldn't be an object in my database. NewsFile is a table and NewsFiles are virtual collections.

> A database operation failed while processing the request.
>   DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See
>   the inner exception for details.  SqlException: Invalid object name
>   'NewsFiles'.  There are pending model changes for ApplicationDbContext
>   In Visual Studio, use the Package Manager Console to scaffold a new
>   migration for these changes and apply them to the database:
>
> PM> Add-Migration [migration name]  PM> Update-Database Alternatively,
>   you can scaffold a new migration and apply it from a command prompt at
>   your project directory:
>
> > dotnet ef migrations add [migration name] 
> >     dotnet ef database update

```
public class News
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NewsFile> NewsFiles { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public Byte[] Content { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NewsFile> NewsFiles { get; set; }
}

public class NewsFile
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NewsId { get; set; }
    public News News { get; set; }
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public File File { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<NewsFile>().HasIndex(nf => new { nf.NewsId, nf.FileId });
    builder.Entity<NewsFile>().HasOne(nf => nf.News).WithMany(n => n.NewsFiles).HasForeignKey(nf => nf.NewsId);
    builder.Entity<NewsFile>().HasOne(nf => nf.File).WithMany(c => c.NewsFiles).HasForeignKey(pc => pc.FileId);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(NewsViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Byte[] file = null;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            model.File.CopyTo(ms);
            file = ms.ToArray();
        }
        model.News.NewsFiles = new List<NewsFile>()
        {
            new NewsFile()
            {
                File = new Models.File() { Content = file, Filename = model.File.FileName }
            }
        };
        _dbContext.News.Add(model.News);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Does NewsFile exist as a table in your DB?

Comment: Yes, NewsFile is a table in my database. The error says NewsFiles is the invalid object name. I even tried specifying the table name like this builder.Entity<NewsFile>().ToTable("NewsFile")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[By default](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/conventions-in-ef-core.aspx):

> EF Core will create database tables for all DbSet properties in a context class with the same name as the property

Thus, you need to override the default convention. I saw your comment that `builder.Entity<NewsFile>().ToTable("NewsFile")` doesn't work. But I just tried it  and it fixes the problem.

When I comment the explicit mapping to table I got the exception `SqlException: Invalid object name 'NewsFiles'`, but it says nothing about pending model changes and migrations. Thus, you somehow got inconsistency between the model and database. As you noted in comment rebuilding database can help

Comment: I deleted the database and let it be re-built and now everything works. I guess something got wacky.

Comment: Improved the answer according to you comment :)